# Internet explorer: Official status of userData behavior?

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer

I've been having trouble with the [userData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms531424%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) behavior in IE9, which I use when an IE version that doesn't support the Web Storage spec is encountered.

Specifically, values don't seem to be saved when the .save() function is executed (in fact, there isn't even a userData folder in `C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\UserData`
, nor is it created upon executing the .save()).

I did some research and the consensus, from a handful of comments on various sites, is that it seems to be disabled in IE9.

Is there some sort of official statement expressing this? If so, is there a way to test whether a given IE version supports it (without browser sniffing)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After some research I seem to have (for the most part) found the answers to my questions.

> Is there some sort of official statement expressing this ("this"
>   meaning that userData is no longer supported in IE9)?

Since I could find no official statement confirming the discontinuation of support for this particular behavior in IE9, comments and complaints across the net will have to suffice: **the userData behavior is not supported in IE9. Additionally, [no behaviors and HTCs are supported in IE10](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh801216%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)**.

> Is there a way to test whether a given IE version supports it (the userData behavior)
>   (without browser sniffing)?

For IE10 and the very early versions of IE that don't support userData, one can check for the existence of the `addBehavior()` member function on the element that the behavior has been attached to:

```
//Assuming "element" has had the userData behavior associated with it through CSS
if(element.addBehavior)
```

Handling IE9 is a little more tricky, since userData behavior related methods are present and do not throw exceptions when correctly used.

Luckily, we can take advantage of the relationship between the data storage mechanism and the `XMLDocument` member that each element with the userData behavior receives. Since this particular member represents the file to be stored to disk when `save()` is called, `element.XMLDocument.xml` is supposed to be updated with each call to `element.addAttribute(key, value)`. If it is not, then we can assume that userData is not supported:

```
//Assuming "element" has had the userData behavior associated with it through CSS
if(element.addBehavior)
{
    element.addAttribute("test", "");

    //If the to-be-saved XML was updated with the attribute we just added
    if(element.XMLDocument.xml.indexOf("test") !== -1) 
    {
        //userData behavior is supported
    }
    else
    {
        //userData behavior is not supported
    } 
}
```

An official statement from MS confirming this drop of support would still be appreciated, as well as a method for determining full userData behavior support without adding a dummy attribute. If you come across either of these, feel free to post them.